# Install Telugu language pack?

Tags: apt, fonts

I just stumbled on this [Wikipedia site](https://te.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E0%B0%B5%E0%B0%BF%E0%B0%A8%E0%B0%BF%E0%B0%AF%E0%B1%8B%E0%B0%97%E0%B0%A6%E0%B0%BE%E0%B0%B0%E0%B1%81_%E0%B0%87%E0%B0%82%E0%B0%9F%E0%B0%B0%E0%B1%8D%E2%80%8C%E0%B0%AB%E0%B1%87%E0%B0%B8%E0%B1%8D) where all the characters are unknown to the system. So apparently this Language is called Telugu and to be able to read it the package `ttf-telugu-fonts` is needed. Though I cannot find this package in the sources. Typing `sudo apt-get install ttf-telugu-fonts` returns with an error that this candidate does not exist. How can I install this Telugu font?

Comment: `sudo apt install fonts-telu`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may try installing the `fonts-indic` package .

To install it open Terminal and run

```
sudo apt-get install fonts-indic
```

Answer (score 2):

There are several font options for Telugu it seems:

```
$: apt-cache search telugu|grep font
fonts-lohit-telu - Lohit TrueType font for Telugu Language
fonts-telu - Meta package to install all Telugu fonts
fonts-telu-extra - Free fonts for Telugu script
fonts-noto-hinted - "No Tofu" font families with large Unicode coverage (hinted)
fonts-teluguvijayam - TrueType fonts for Telugu script (te)
ttf-indic-fonts-core - Core collection of free fonts for languages of India
```

Installing any of them should get you working font rendering of Telugu.